# Fast binary counter minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

How do I make fast binary counter in minecraft bedrock? Currently I'm using hopper and the transition is too slow, perhaps there is simple way to build fast binary counter in minecraft.

Comment: Um, make a [J/K flip-flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_cell_(computing)#Floating-gate_MOS_memory_cells) and then [daisy-chaining them like so](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/229590)?